# Morphia createDatastore won't accept com.mongodb.client.MongoClient object with new mongo driver version

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Since upgrading from mongo-java-driver to mongodb-driver-sync(4.6.1), I am unable to use createDatastore method because it's looking for a com.mongodb.MongoClient object (which is discontinued) instead of
com.mongodb.client.MongoClient object:

```
client = MongoClients.create(settings);
datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, databaseName);
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this? I've tried casting but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The changing of `com.mongodb.MongoClient` to `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` for Morphia library was released in 2.0.0:

> https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1319

So you should also update your Morphia library to a [newer version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dev.morphia.morphia/morphia-core), for example:

```
implementation group: 'dev.morphia.morphia', name: 'morphia-core', version: '2.3.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade to morphia 2 as it requires java 11. I'm using java 8.